# Why can't some CPanel Webmail users login from only one location?

Tags: email, webmail

I need some help with a Cpanel Webmail situation our client is having. This is my first question here. Hope I'm clear in explaining:

Three users(and possibly more) at one of our clients can't login to their webmail or access email through outlook. When I go to https:// IPofServer:2096 on my computer, which is located in a different location than the client, I can log in to webmail under all three accounts. When I remotely connect to the three client users' computers and do the exact same thing from their browser, I get a message at the Webmail screen saying that the credentials don't work. ( I don't have the exact wording at the moment, but it's a generic wrong user/pw message) When I searched the web, all I could find was stuff about opening ports and IP deny list, but all the necessary ports are open and the IP deny list is empty.(The users have no problem connecting to webmail, just their credentials don't work) I'm also bypassing any incorrect dns resolution issues by using the ip of the server instead of the name.

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas about why this is happening. It really makes no sense to me.

Thanks!

Comment: What did cPanel support tell you?

Answer (score 3):

I figure it out. cPHulk Brute Force Protection had the users/IP blacklisted. I went to  Home » Security Center » cPHulk Brute Force Protection  and cleared the blacklist and also whitelisted the public IP of the client's office.